# Potential performance improvement from inserting chunks of DOM elements dynamically as needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm looking at ways to improve performance of my single page web app, which will need to run on a variety of devices including lower-end phones.

I've got 8 modals (Twitter Bootstrap but this question applies to any framework) that add over 200 elements to my total page DOM element count (783). Is it worth having these as strings in Javascript rather than code in the HTML, and injecting them when needed into the DOM immediately before display, then removing them afterward? Would strip live DOM size down by a quarter, thus making e.g. JQuery element searches quicker, lighterweight page etc.

I was thinking to use JQuery's $.detach() and $.append() for example

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you modify the DOM, you take a performance hit because the browser will have to "reflow" and "repaint" the UI. As such, keeping those modifications to a minimum will help, however doing modifications in batches absorbs some of that performance hit (i.e. changing 3 DOM elements separately is more expensive than changing all 3 at once). So, group together your DOM changes as best you can.

The actual mechanism you use to inject the new content could either be by:

1. Passing a string of HTML to the HTML parser and asking it to parse
   on demand the string. This is essentially the same as the process
   that happens when the page is being parsed from the server. Using
   the standard `.innerHTML` or JQuery `.html()` accomplishes this.
2. You could also build up the DOM element in memory first and then
   inject that node into the DOM at the right time (i.e. `document.createElement` or `document.createDocumentFragment`). I generally favor
   this approach as it is more programmatic, vastly reduces the
   possibility of string concatenation and quotation errors and is
   cleaner to read. From a performance standpoint, this gives you the
   benefit of getting some of the work done prior to DOM injection
   time. This would be the equivalent of the DOM `.appendChild()` or
   the JQuery `.append()` methods.

In the end, today's modern user agents handle DOM changes much better than they used to and either approach is viable. It's the really bad techniques (like modifying the DOM in a loop) that you want to stay away from that, in the end, will make a difference.

Comment: Great info thanks. Is it worth doing at all though, vs just leaving all the modals in the HTML code (ie. in the live DOM) which I guess any of my JQuery selectors will have to parse through to get to other stuff? Or perhaps it's worth putting the modals at the end my HTML code? Thanks

Comment: @AlexKerr If the modals will be needed sooner or later, it's best to put them into the HTML from the start as including them in  the initial building of the DOM isn't going to add very much overhead.